# Get matching rows in two different dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Thanks in advance- the problem is to compare rows of two separate dataframes of csv files; with and without column headings. 
I want to match rows in second dataframe to rows in dataframe one. I cannot use merge because both don't have common column names to merge with.

1: The first dataframe have headings

2: Second dataframe is without headings.

3: get the position of the match

I have tried this:

```
    df1 = pd.read_csv(data1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(data2)
    def test1():
    for index, rows in df1.iterrows():
        if rows in (df2):
            return nrows
```

Datasets:

**first dataset:**
[image: first dataset]

**Second dataset:**

[image: Second dataset]

Comment: Don’t use `iterrows()`, `itertuples()` is far better. Can you share the actual content of the DataFrames or files? See: [mcve].

Comment: NH23345 mountain2B 936 56.870342 -4.199001
NH136714 A' Chailleach 997 57.6938 -5.128715
NH681041 A' Chailleach 929.2 57.109564 -4.179285
NH094147 A' Chraileag (A' Chralaig) 1120 57.184186 -5.154837
NH008231 A' Ghlas-bheinn 918 57.25509 -5.303687
NH007749 A' Mhaighdean 967 57.719644 -5.34672
NN604762 AA 973.2 56.857002 -4.290668

Comment: Hill Name Height Latitude Longitude Osgrid
A' Bhuidheanach Bheag 936 56.870342 -4.199001 NN660775
A' Chailleach 997 57.6938 -5.128715 NH136714
A' Chailleach 929.2 57.109564 -4.179285 NH681041
A' Chraileag (A' Chralaig) 1120 57.184186 -5.154837 NH094147
A' Ghlas-bheinn 918 57.25509 -5.303687 NH008231
A' Mhaighdean 967 57.719644 -5.34672 NH007749
A' Mharconaich 973.2 56.857002 -4.290668 NN604762
Am Basteir 934 57.247931 -6.202982 NG465253
Am Bodach 1031.8 56.741727 -4.983393 NN176650
Am Faochagach 953 57.771801 -4.853899 NH303793

Comment: The first is the first dataset without column names, while the second is the dataset with column names. These are stored in separate csv files

Comment: Probably better to include that in your post, eh.

Comment: (Ideally not as an image, since the whole point is for other people to be able to execute your program. Again, see: [mcve].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add header to the second `dataframe` with:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Or, much better, define them in the first place when reading the file with:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2, header=None, names=df1.columns.tolist())
```

And then `inner merge` them to stay with just the rows that exists identically in both:

```
united_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Aryerez. Assigning df1 columns to df2 in case of not not identical dataset and merging will mean not having the right column headings

Comment: @happycoder If the datasets are not identical, the entire question is meaningless. What exactally do you want to match with what, if they don't mean the same?

Comment: Sorry @Aryere,  aim is to read df1 row by row; if any row match to rows in df2 flag it.

Comment: Ok, but if the columns in `df2` do not neccesary mean the same as the columns in `df1`, then it's not a match. Let's say for example that the 3rd column in `df2` means "Longtitude", while the 4th column in `df2` means "Latitude" (the opposite than their meaning in `df1`). How could you determine that they do match, if the *Longtitude* in one row in `df1` matches the *Latitude* (and **not** the *Longtitude*) in `df2`?